# Identifying related words with the use of Wildcards in c++

Tags: c++, wildcard

Ok, I've been trying to come up with a solution to my problem.  The problem is:
Given a list of 3 letter words (size of the list is irrelevant I think), how can I identify those words in the list that differ with the first word in the list by at most one letter.
Say I have the word pat
then I would like to identify all the words in the list that are:

pa_   such as pay
p_t   such as pot
_ot   such as rot

Is there a way to implement wildcards in c++?

Comment: You could the std::regex library.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: But that's c++11. Better use something older

Comment: @BeniBela : Older is better? In any case there's [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) and [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/).

Comment: @Tony The Lion, what do you mean.  I don't know about that library, I've never used it before.

Comment: @Cyrax5710 here is a reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/      and here is an online generator to practice with: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @ildjarn: you can assume it is available, better tested, less bugs, ...

Comment: nothing is wrong with regex. regex can be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at the **strcmp** function and some of the other related functions listed here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

....or you could use **regex** like Tony the Lion just said.

EDIT:
....also is the **strcspn** function

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/

```
/* strcspn example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "fcba73";
  char keys[] = "1234567890";
  int i;
  i = strcspn (str,keys);
  printf ("The first number in str is at position %d.\n",i+1);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

The first number in str is at position 5

There's also **strstr** which finds the first occurence of str1 in str2.

for instance:

```
 string str1 = "po";
 string str2 = "potlock";

 char * pch;
  pch = strstr (str2,str1);
```

Second EDIT:

you could definitely do a loop with

```
if (strcspn (str1,str2)){
    //there is at least one match
}else {

//no matches
```

}

Comment: There is absolutely...totally, nothing, wrong with my answer. if you want to do a long loop around...then i guess you could ....but there are tools available in the c++ library that really do help. and there is nothing wrong with regex.

Comment: The library functions strcmp, strstr and strcspn are of no use here.  If you don't see why, ask yourself how they can be used to match "cat" with "cpt" (bearing in mind that "cat" *is* a match for "cpt" given the requirements of this exercise).

Comment: the question was: "how can I identify those words in the list that differ with the first word in the list by at MOST one letter."

Comment: Yes it is, but I think you misunderstand the question.  All of the words in the list have 3 letters, for example cat, cot, cap, dog, pig, mat.  In that example, the answer is cot, cap, mat because those words differ from cat by at most one letter.

Comment: yes, but you would first want to know 1: if there was any matches at all in the first place, maybe by using strcmp....otherwise it is a waste of time to begin with. 2: And if you used strcspn you would find where the letter is that matches. I honestly don't see what is wrong with using any of those methods!

Comment: any also, looking at the question again now...i'm wondering if they meant list as an an actual c++ list of words....or if they are using an array of strings....or a vector or...well, i bet they are probably using an array.

Comment: I can only urge you to re-read the assignment at this point.  You are trying to solve a different problem.  The standard C library routines like strcmp and strcspn (or their C++ STL equivalents) are no use in this exercise.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25403/discussion-between-user1066524-and-jarmod)

Answer (score 0):

[This may be more complex than the assignment requires but it avoids slow string comparisons and regular expressions]

Given that everything is a 3-letter word, you might consider representing each word as a 4-byte integer.  For example, in "pat" the letter 'p' is 0x70 (ascii), 'a' is 0x61 and 't' is 0x74 so represent "pat" by the integer 0x706174.  Do likewise for all the 3-letter words in the test list.

Next, the combination of tests required for 2 of the 3 letters to match (in same order) is:

- p?t where the test is 0x70??74
- ?at where the test is 0x??6174
- pa? where the test is 0x7061??

PS can I just add that the stackoverflow 'code sample' button which is suppose to reformat your selection as code is weird in Firefox.  This 1-minute post has taken 20 minutes to format!

```
// assume array words[] of strings
int word0 = calc_int_from_word(words[0]);

for (int ii = 1; ii < words.count; ii++)
{
  int wordii = calc_int_from_word(words[ii]);

  if (wordii & 0xFFFF00 == word0 & 0xFFFF00 ||
      wordii & 0xFF00FF == word0 & 0xFF00FF ||
      wordii & 0x00FFFF == word0 & 0x00FFFF)
  {
    // words[ii] matches words[0] in at least two letters
  }
}
```

Comment: how is this any faster than string comparisons?

Comment: Any string operation is slow compared to basic integer arithmetic.  If nothing else it has the overhead of function calls, stack manipulation, and possibly heap allocation.

Comment: yes. I agree with you on that....but not when you are only trying to only find the words in the list that differ with the first word in the list by at MOST one letter.

Comment: You misunderstand what it means to "differ by at most one letter".  Your strstr example with "po" and "potlock" is evidence of this.

Comment: no.... I was altering a c++ example from the cplusplus.com site to explain how strstr works.....

Comment: Why explain how strstr works?  It's not useful in this exercise.

Comment: There are many string functions from the c++  library that are very useful for string manipulation and string matching. although, regex is probably the most efficient, but the OP didn't seem to know about regex yet so I was trying to introduce something less difficult/complex. and bitwise operators are probably way above them at this point.